# How to insert multipleRows in oracle using sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I need to insert multiple Rows in oracle database, I use this command line:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO PHMR_VIP (PHMR_VIP_ID,PHMR_VIP_NOM,PHMR_VIP_PRENOM) VALUES (SQ_PHMR_VIP.nextval, 'dfdf', 'dfdfd')
  INTO PHMR_VIP (PHMR_VIP_ID,PHMR_VIP_NOM,PHMR_VIP_PRENOM) VALUES (SQ_PHMR_VIP.nextval, 'ffdf', 'dfdf')
  INTO PHMR_VIP (PHMR_VIP_ID,PHMR_VIP_NOM,PHMR_VIP_PRENOM) VALUES (SQ_PHMR_VIP.nextval, 'mohfdfd','fdfdf')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

But, I have oracle error:

> ORA-00001: violation de contrainte unique (PHMR.PHMR_VIP_PK)

How can I resolve this please? I need to do a bulkInsert with column PHMR_VIP_ID as a sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
INSERT INTO PHMR_VIP (PHMR_VIP_ID,PHMR_VIP_NOM,PHMR_VIP_PRENOM) 
SELECT SQ_PHMR_VIP.nextval, col1, col2
FROM (
  SELECT 'dfdf' AS col1, 'dfdfd' AS col2 FROM dual
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ffdf', 'dfdf'    FROM dual
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'mohfdfd','fdfdf' FROM dual
);
```

Comment: I have this error `ORA-02287: numéro de séquence non autorisé ici`

Comment: I have now this error `ORA-00933: la commande SQL ne se termine pas correctement`

Comment: @user1428798 Try last time, I removed alias. Now should work :)

Answer (score 0):

For some, you have to use `SELECT 1 FROM dual;` instead of `SELECT * FROM dual;`. See this reference: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2457262. This is because there is only 1 row in dual.

That doesn't help in this instance though, because you can't use sequences with `SELECT ALL`, per this article: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1038439, at least not the way you have. You can if you have a trigger that catches each `nextval` call and updates the value manually, but as mentioned further in the postings, it can decrease performance.

The recommendation is to use multiple inserts rather than an insert all.

Hope this helps.

-C§